# Help me for Json unknown problem

Tags: .net, json, twitter

I'm working with a project that use Twitter API to get mentions timeline of my account and it return as Json, problem is I cant run it because of this error

> Could not load file or assembly 'Newtonsoft.Json, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

How can I solve this problem, Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't say that's an unknown problem.  You're obviously missing an assembly reference to Newtonsoft.Json.

That assembly either needs to be placed in your applications root directory or in your GAC.

You can get the latest build for this assembly @ [Json.NET](http://json.codeplex.com/releases/view/43775)

Comment: But i can run it in this morning, and I change anything

Comment: Have you tried clearing your ASP.NET temporary directory? I've found that clearing out this directory and rebuilding your solution can clear up issues with assembly references. C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files